# How to force a redis client to throw an exception when a stream data structure is expired?

Tags: redis, lettuce

This is the senario expressed in redis commands:

```
127.0.0.1:6381> xadd test 1 field1 data1
"1-0"
127.0.0.1:6381> xrange test - +
1) 1) "1-0"
   2) 1) "field1"
      2) "data1"
127.0.0.1:6381> expire test 10
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6381> xrange test - +
1) 1) "1-0"
   2) 1) "field1"
      2) "data1"
127.0.0.1:6381> xrange test - +
(empty list or set)
```

In this sequence the stream data structure is set to expire in 10s. After 10s, the `xrange` command returns `(empty list or set)`. I can confirm with the `keys` command that the key `test` does not exist any more.

If I translate the above sequence into lettuce, I find the last `xrange` command will simply return an empty list. It does not throw any exception at all even if the key no longer exist.

```
    key = 'test'
    slot = SlotHash.getSlot(key);
    var nodeId = cluster.getPartitions().getPartitionBySlot(slot).getNodeId();
    shard = cluster.getConnection(nodeId);
    shard.sync().xrange(key, Range.from(Boundary.unbounded(), Boundary.unbounded()), 100)
```

Is it possible to make xrange throws an exception when the key is expired?

I have read the documentation of keyspace notification (https://redis.io/topics/notifications). However since it is "fire and forget", the delivery of notification is not guaranteed. Therefore I cannot use keyspace notification as solution.

Comment: What about `xlen` to check it and throw exception if it is zero ?

Comment: If `xrange` returns an empty list, it means the key does not exist. It's might have been deleted, or expired, or never existed. So if `xrange` returns an empty list, you can throw in your application code.

Comment: I am actually surprised that no exception is thrown, even if I call `keys` on the expired key. In `redis-cli`, at least `keys` will show an 'ERR' message.

Comment: Because the error you see when you run `keys` is related to the syntax, there is nothing wrong to query a non existing key via using any command.

Comment: Ahh... you're right. Hopefully it is a quick question: then how can I tell the difference between empty key value and a cache miss? Both will return null, right?

Comment: It depends on the data structure - you may set an empty string(key exists) - but after you remove all elements from list, set, sorted sets the key no longer exists. `exists` will return 0 for these types, while return 1 for string.